# Export to Excel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, excel

Having some trouble exporting to  downloadable Excel content, using AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC. My end results is nothing happens.

Sample ASP.NET Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(Model form)
{
    var gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = _service.getSomeStuff(form);
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Stuff.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
    return File(temp, "application/ms-excel");
}
```

Angular Controller Method: -> triggered via ng-click handler

```
function exportToExcel() {
    $http.post('/Controller/ExportToExcel/', vm.Model)
           .success(function (data) {
           })
           .error(function (data) {
                alerts.error(data);
            });
}
```

View:

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.exportToExcel()">click me</a>
```

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you're calling `Response.End()` before you're returning File. I imagine that causes issues

Comment: @user167698 , use either `Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Stuff.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();`
 or `byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
    return File(temp, "application/ms-excel");`. Don't use both.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried with and without the Response.End(). No difference in result. The "ExportToExcel(Model form)" method does seem to produce a download, if called from a standard form submit.

Comment: this seems to do it too.function exportToExcel() {
  $http.post('/Controller/ExportToExcel/', Model)
            .success(function (data) {
               var element = angular.element('<a/>');
                element.attr({
                      href: 'data:application/ms-excel;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
                      target: '_blank',
                      download: 'file.xslt'
                  })[0].click();
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    alerts.error(data);
              });
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this, without the need for AJAX or any JS. Tweaking the Razor code is all that is required.

Secondly, my personal suggestion would be to not convert to Excel file at all. The reason being, the user is required to have Office on his local machine. It also means, should you upload your project to a website, that server machine will need Office installed in order to produce your excel file.

That being said, I would suggest just using a CSV file. If a user has Office installed, they would be able to use Excel to view the file like any spreadsheet.

Here is some code that will create a CSV called Export.csv from a dbset in your dbcontext, done using `StringBuilder` and `Reflection`.

```
public ActionResult Export()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        var tmp = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();     
        Type comp = tmp.GetType();                // get type
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in comp.GetProperties())
        {
            str.Append(prop.Name + ",");          //set column names
        }
        str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        foreach (object item in db.Users)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    string a = prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
                    str.Append(a + ",");
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    str.Append("null" + ",");           //for nulls, append string with "null"
                }
            }
            str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        string csv = str.ToString();
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Export.csv");
    }
```

You can then access download the file with a link on your view like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Export", "Controller")">click me</a>
```

Hope this helps.